Java - Jackson XML serializing with dynamic child
I need to generate 2 xml files which are practically identical except for the name of the first element after the root element
Add.xml
<root>
    <addPerson>
        <person idPerson="1"/>
    </addPerson>
</root>

Delete.xml
<root>
    <deletePerson>
        <person idPerson="1"/>
    </deletePerson>
</root>

Between the two only the addPerson and deletePerson elements change.
The closest thing I've been able to get to the goal is this (but the result isn't exactly what I need):
pom.xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
    <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
    <version>2.13.3</version>
</dependency>

Person.java
public class Person {
    @JacksonXmlProperty(isAttribute = true)
    private String idPerson;
    // ...
}

AddPerson.java
public class AddPerson {
    private Person person;
    // ...
}

DeletePerson.java
public class DeletePerson {
    private Person person;
    // ...
}

DeleteRoot.java
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
public class Root {
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include =JsonTypeInfo.As.WRAPPER_OBJECT)
    @JsonSubTypes({
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "addPerson", value = AddPerson.class),
        @JsonSubTypes.Type(name = "deletePeson" , value = DeletePerson.class)
    })
    Object addOrDeletePerson;
    // ...
}

Main.java
public class Main {
    static final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        Root rootAdd = new Root(new AddPerson(new Person("1")));
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(rootAdd));
        
        Root rootDelete = new Root(new DeletePerson(new Person("1")));
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(rootDelete));
    }
}

Result
<root><addOrDeletePerson><addPerson><person idPerson="1"/></addPerson></addOrDeletePerson></root>
<root><addOrDeletePerson><deletePeson><person idPerson="1"/></deletePeson></addOrDeletePerson></root>

What's not good is that an addOrDeletePerson element is added which I don't need.
Some idea?
Thank you

You could try something like that:
@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
public class DeleteRoot {
    DeletePerson deletePerson;
    // ...
}

@JacksonXmlRootElement(localName = "root")
public class AddRoot {
    AddPerson addPerson;
    // ...
}

public class Main {
    static final XmlMapper xmlMapper = new XmlMapper();
    
    public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
        AddRoot rootAdd = new AddRoot(new AddPerson(new Person("1")));
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(rootAdd));
        
        DeleteRoot rootDelete = new DeleteRoot(new DeletePerson(new Person("1")));
        System.out.println(xmlMapper.writeValueAsString(rootDelete));
    }
}

By specifying localName = "root" for both *Root classes, it should produce your expected result.

it works, but I was hoping there was something like annotation JAXB @XmlElements({@XmlElement(name = "addPerson", type = AddPerson.class),@XmlElement(name = "deletePeson", type = DeletePeson.class)})
